# How update component after click and url change?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I try use vue-router, but something went wrong.

On page rendered router-link, by click url changed. localhost/#/ -> localhost/#/contacts but component steal main page. Update only if page reload.

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App from './index.vue';
import Error404 from './404.vue';
import Routes from './route';


Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'hash',
    routes: Routes
});

window.onload = () => {
    new Vue({
        router: router,
        el: '#app-container',
        data: {
            currentRoute: window.location.hash.split('#')[1]
        },
        computed: {
            ViewComponent () {
                return Routes.filter(item => item.path == this.currentRoute)[0] || Error404
            }
        },
        render (h) { return h(this.ViewComponent.component ? this.ViewComponent.component : this.ViewComponent) }
    });
}
```

**route.js**

```
const routes = [
    {path: '/', component: mainPage},
    {path: '/example1', component: examplePage},
    {path: '/example2', component: exampleForm},
    {path: '/contacts', component: contacts}
];

export default routes
```

**index.vue**

```
<template lang="jade">
    div(id="app")
        router-link(to="/example1") Example1
        br
        router-link(to="/example2") Example2
        br
        router-link(to="/contacts") Contacts
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
    export default {

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you import every component map in the route.js?

Answer (score 0):

I fix problem by add

```
watch: {
            '$route'(to, from) {
                this.$router.go(this.$router.currentRoute)
            }
        }
```

for main.js, but i think this is very bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `router-view`. [this is the component responsible to render the component](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-view.html) that the router needs to display

please consider this code structure based on [official boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack):

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

**index.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
    <router-link to="example1">example1</router-link>
    <router-link to="example2">example2</router-link>

  </div>
</template>
```

**index.js (like your route.js)**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import example1 from '@/components/example.vue'
import example2 from '@/components/example2.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/example-1',
      name: 'example-1',
      component: example1
    }
    {
      path: '/example-2',
      name: 'example-2',
      component: example2
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: [Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

(found in <Root>)